# show data from database based on which checkbox is clicked in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, checkbox

If I click on a check-box then it should connect the database and fetch result. Check-box labels are also fetched from database (through PHP) and those labels are also tables in the database.
Upto now, I am able to fetch the database through PHP-JS-AJAX call [reference: http://grocery.sketchmeglobal.com > Drinks > Check-boxes] but each time a check-box is clicked it is over-writing the previous one.

How to solve it?

My Code-part:: JS-file :

```
    $no_of_rows = $('#num_of_rows').val();
    if($no_of_rows=== '' || $no_of_rows === null){
       alert('undefined');
    }
    else {
        $no_of_rows = $('#num_of_rows').val();  
    } 
  $('.css-checkbox').click(function() {

    for(var i=1; i<= $no_of_rows ; i++){
        checked =  $('#checkbox'+i).prop('checked');
        if(checked === true) {

            $searchTable = $('#checklabel'+i).text(); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: 'searchResult.php',
            data: 'searchTable=' + $searchTable,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#search-result').html(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('it\'s broken');
            },
            complete: function() {
//                alert('clicked at-> checkbox'+i);
            }
        });
        }
        else{

        }

    }
```

});

Comment: Please share your codebase.

Comment: Edited. Is it enough or do I need to post the PHP file as well where within an ID, I am collecting all the data with following query, 
"$query = "select * from product_details where sub_category='$sub_table_name'";"

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is that your results are overwriting previous results, then use `append` in your success handler and not `html`

```
    success: function(data) {
        $('#search-result').append(data);
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is solved now and what I did was changed the ajax code and a part of SQL query. 
Ajax part:  search += "#" + $searchTable; // to gather all table name

SQL Part: "select * from product_details where sub_category IN('$sql_sub')";
PHP Part: $table_name = substr($table_name, 1);
$sql_sub = str_replace('#', '\',\'',$table_name);

Just wanted to share it since someone can save time with it. 
Cheers...

Comment: glad you solved it. its worth answering your own question formally so you can layout a proper solution for someone with the same issue.